# Binary Search Tree 'Int object not iterable'

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, iterable

So I'm fairly new to programming and I am trying to make my delete function in my binary search tree to delete on the side that has the highest depth of nodes. However, I keep getting an error once I try to run it and I know it is a simple fix but I cannot figure it out after reading a few similar questions on here.

Here is my error I get:

```
C:\Python33\python.exe "C:/Users/koopt_000/Desktop/College/Sophomore Semester 2/Computer Science 231/Chapter7/Test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/koopt_000/Desktop/College/Sophomore Semester 2/Computer Science 231/Chapter7/Test.py", line 10, in <module>
    a.delete(tree, 9)
  File "C:\Users\koopt_000\Desktop\College\Sophomore Semester 2\Computer Science 231\Chapter7\BinarySearchTree.py", line 111, in delete
    ldepth == max(self.height(root.left))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here are my following parts of code starting from my TreeNodes, to BST(main function), and then my test code.

```
 class TreeNode(object):

    def __init__(self, data = None, left=None, right=None):
        self.item = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.item)
```

---

```
from TreeNode import TreeNode


class BST(object):

    #------------------------------------------------------------

    def __init__(self):

        """create empty binary search tree
        post: empty tree created"""

        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    def delete(self, root, item, ldepth = 0, rdepth = 0 ):

        """remove item from binary search tree
        post: item is removed from the tree"""


        if ldepth == 0:
            ldepth == max(self.height(root.left))
        if rdepth == 0:
            rdepth == max(self.height(root.right))

        if ldepth > rdepth:
            depth = ldepth
            print(depth)
        elif ldepth < rdepth:
            depth = rdepth
            print(depth)
        else:
            depth = ldepth
            print(depth)

        self.root = self._subtreeDelete(root, item, depth)

    #------------------------------------------------------------

    def _subtreeDelete(self, root, item, depth):

        if root is None:   # Empty tree, nothing to do
           return None
        if item < root.item:                             # modify left
            root.left = self._subtreeDelete(root.left, item)
        elif item > root.item:                           # modify right
            root.right = self._subtreeDelete(root.right, item)
        else:                                            # delete root
            if root.left is None:                        # promote right subtree
                root = root.right
            elif root.right is None:                     # promote left subtree
                root = root.left
            else:
                # root node can't be deleted, overwrite it with max of 
                #    left subtree and delete max node from the subtree
                root.item, root.left = self._subtreeDelMax(root.left)
        return root

    #------------------------------------------------------------

    def _subtreeDelMax(self, root):

        if root.right is None:           # root is the max 
            return root.item, root.left  # return max and promote left subtree
        else:
            # max is in right subtree, recursively find and delete it
            maxVal, root.right = self._subtreeDelMax(root.right)
            return maxVal, root  

    def height(self, root):
        if root is None:
            return 0
        else:
            return max(self.height(root.left), self.height(root.right)) + 1
```

---

```
from BinarySearchTree import BST
from TreeNode import TreeNode

tree = TreeNode(4, TreeNode(2, TreeNode(1), TreeNode(3)), TreeNode (7, TreeNode(6),TreeNode(9)))


a = BST()
a._subtreeInsert(tree, 10)
a._subtreeInsert(tree, 5)
a.delete(tree, 9)

print("PRE-ORDER TRANSVERSE:")
print(a.preOrder(tree))
print("IN-ORDER TRANSVERSE:")
print(a.inOrder(tree))
print("POST-ORDER TRANSVERSE:")
print(a.postOrder(tree))

print("The max depth of the tree is,", a.height(tree),"nodes deep.")
print("There are,", a.treeSize(tree),"nodes in this tree.")
```

Could anyone tell me whats wrong? I need this to work in order to make my delete function work properly,

Comment: What do you expect `max(self.height(root.left))` to do?

Comment: I thought it would give the depth of the nodes on the left side...

Comment: I guess I forgot that I had it in my height function, but if I take the max away it just returns 0 as my answer

Comment: That's because you have more bugs. You're using `==` instead of `=` for assignment.

Comment: But self.height is already calling max

Answer (score 0):

The max() function in python takes an iterable object, like a list, in which it can iterates over to find the max value.

```
self.height(root.left)
```

is a single int, essentially a single value which is not iteratable, which is throwing your error.

Comment: But when I do that it return '0'. As the max.

Comment: well your code has `def height(self, root):` as the method definition and when you call `ldepth == self.height(root.left)` you have only given it one parameter and then under your height function definition you have `def height(self, root):
        if root is None:
            return 0` so it will return 0 everytime. so you need to add that root param -> `self.height(root.left, *theroot*)`

Comment: sorry for messy response.. I hate formatting comments on this site.

Comment: Okay, I added root to my self.height so now my code looks like this `self.height(root.left, root)` how now I get this following error: `TypeError: height() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Comment: height takes two argument including self .Inthis case self.height(root.left, root) you are giving three argument.